# How to design my GWT application on DB level

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I thought and read so much about GWT, AppEngine and CloudSQL last week, but I still can't find the right setup for my app on DB level.

My requirements are:

- I want to use GWT, since I'm good in Java
- I'm creating a big data mining project.
- I'll analyse the data from the DB with Matlab (using the Database Toolbox over JDBC)
- Later, users can use the application as a collaborative web 2.0 application
- I want to have an easy solution, where I don't run every day while developing into stupid 
  Class*Excepitions due to incorrect design

I thought about the following setups:

1. GWT + Appengine + CloudSQL + local MySQL DB:

   I'll try to keep the CouldSQL DB and my MySQL DB in sync. Then I can run my data mining algorithms locally using the MySQL db.
2. GWT + MySQL: I'll connect GWT directly to my local MySQL db.
3. GWT + Appengine + NoSQL data store +synchronize data with local MySQL db using e.g. Approcket (http://code.google.com/p/approcket/). I'll then run my data mining algorithms on the synchronized MySQL db.

Comments:

I like the possibility on 1. and 3. to deploy my app quickly with the advantage of scaling. With solution 2. I'll need to host it myself. Moreover I don't have a standardized (google) solution.

On solution 1. and 3. I worry, that it is very complicated to keep my cloud and local data in sync.

On solution 2. I can't use the advantages of AppEngine. Moreover it'll be more difficult to set it up than the solutions 1. and 3. proposed from google.

What do you think is the best and easiest solution for my problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you have a budget?  Note that Cloud SQL is [**not free**](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/billing).

Comment: I'm willing to pay 10$/month during development phase and up to $30/month when it's running. What I've seen I'll be below that limit with Cloud SQL. So that shouldn't be an issue.